# QGIS shapefile layers to database geometry type

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgis, geoserver

I have opened Arcgis shapefile with QGIS. And I used QGIS database manager tool to create table and import data to postgresql database. Database manager is creating and importing success. But there is an issue about geometry types.

```
Shapefile Geometry         Postgis Table Geometry

 - Polygon         ==>     MultiPolygon 
 - Polyline        ==>     MultiPolyline
 - Point           ==>     MultiPoint
```

Polygon type is creating as Multi on postgis table. What do you think about this?

Comment: I'm having trouble reconciling your tags with what's in the body of your question. Is the shapefile created using ArcGIS for Desktop or by some other means?

Comment: For general usage there is only advantages in having `MultiPolygons` (you should not notice any difference with a shape-file). PostGIS's `Polygon` and other non-multi geometry types doesn't allow usage of multipart geometry, so you won't be able to store for example such country as   Japan as a single feature.

Comment: This issue may be a bug in QGIS 2.6: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11542 - similarly, 'POINT' is being output only as 'MULTIPOINT' for GPX files (which fails).

Comment: I don't think there is nothing strange about it: it is normal that when you import data into postgis you must choose if you need a layer that accepts multipart geometries or not. By default the layers are created as "multi", but the user can choose otherwise (and when editing, if a multipart geometry is added it will give error on save).

Comment: @Simbamangu that is another issue: for some reason in QGIS 2.6 shapefiles are always read as "multi". This gives error when saving to formats that do not allow "multi" as GPX.